# Where to store static things like website settings in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

So lets say you've got some website settings like `minimum content length` and `default avatar size` and so on. Now these settings are not going to change very often. So what would be the best way of storing them?

Should they be stored in the database and then queried only once to add them into a session variable, maybe a cookie, or cache? Should they just be queried from the database every time they are needed? Are there any other ways of storing data in meteor that I am not aware of?What would be the most efficient way of approaching something like this?

Comment: You could store them in a text-file or a json-file or an xml-file

Comment: then simply read and write to it?

Comment: If you go with a file-based solution, then you could use `Assets` http://docs.meteor.com/#assets

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Meteor.settings`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings) which was designed for cases like this. On your deployment environment (could be separate: devel, staging and production) set the settings as a JSON-stringified string in the `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable. In your code access run-time settings from `Meteor.settings`.

If your settings are not different depending on environment, you can as well just keep them in a JS file in your project.